# Validate json property with dependency of other property in Play 2.4

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework-2.0

I have

```
case class AclRuleScope(kind: String, value: String)
```

and i want convert `Json` to `AclRuleScope` with restrictions:

`type` may be only: "default" | "user" | "group" | "domain"

`value` may be only email if type is "user" | "group", and some string in another cases

I have object with `Reader` and `Writer`, but i cant understand how can i get `type` value when reading `value`:

```
object AclRuleScope {

  implicit val aclRuleScopeRead = (
    (__ \ "type").read[String](pattern("^(default|user|group|domain)$".r)) and
      (__ \ "value").read[String](
          email keepAnd 
          filter(
              ValidationError("error.scope.value")
          )( ??? == JsString("user") || ??? == JsString("group")))
    )(this.apply _)

}
```

What must be in `???`

Answer (score 2):

`JsConstraints#filter` has the following signature

```
def filter[A](otherwise: ValidationError)(p: A => Boolean)(implicit reads: Reads[A])
```

when you write

```
filter(ValidationError("error.scope.value"))(??? == JsString("user") || ??? == JsString("group")))
```

the code `(??? == JsString("user") || ??? == JsString("group"))` is actually the second parameter to filter, it should therefore be a predicate of `A => Boolean`. Also since this is applied after the `email` reads which is a `Reads[String]`, your actual `A` is `String` so you should drop the `JsString`.

The smallest change you could write is:

```
implicit val aclRuleScopeRead = (
  (__ \ "type").read[String](pattern("^(default|user|group|domain)$".r)) and
    (__ \ "value").read[String](
      email keepAnd
        filter(
          ValidationError("error.scope.value")
        )(x => x == "user" || x == "group"))
  ).tupled
```

I strongly encourage you to extract the predicate to its own method:

```
def isValidEmail: (String) => Boolean = {
  x => x == "user" || x == "group"
}
```

and write your reads as

```
implicit val aclRuleScopeRead = (
  (__ \ "type").read[String](pattern("^(default|user|group|domain)$".r)) and
    (__ \ "value").read[String](
      email keepAnd filter(ValidationError("error.scope.value"))(isValidEmail))
  ).tupled
```

even better you could have

```
val validEmail = email keepAnd filter(ValidationError("error.scope.value"))(isValidEmail))
```

and write

```
implicit val aclRuleScopeRead = (
  (__ \ "type").read[String](pattern("^(default|user|group|domain)$".r)) and
    (__ \ "value").read[String](validEmail)
  ).tupled
```

Upon clarification in the comments, you only want to parse the email if the type is "user" or "group" returning an empty string if not the case.

The answer is close to the solution outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34188986/add-optional-property-with-json-transformers-in-playframework-2-4)

The reads of the `value` field first needs to check the value of the `type` field. The condition on the type field looks like :

(__ \ "type").read[String].filter(ValidationError("error.scope.value"))(isEmailType)

where isEmailType is defined as

```
def isEmailType: (String) => Boolean = { x => x == "user" || x == "group" }
```

This will return a read that gives a `JsSuccess` if the type is `user` or `group` and a `JsError` otherwise. From the comments we know that we should return the empty string if the type is not `user` or `group`, the reads can become:

```
(__ \ "type").read[String]
            .filter(ValidationError("error.scope.value"))(isEmailType)
            .orElse Reads.pure("")
```

Which is safe and will never return a `JsError`. This is fine since there is a dedicated `reads` to enforce the validation on `type`, the reads we are currently manipulating is only there as part of the validation of `value`. 
Now we need to change the read to parse `value` if the parsing is a `JsSuccess` :

```
(__ \ "type").read[String]
            .filter(ValidationError("error.scope.value"))(isEmailType)
            .flatMap(_ => (__ \ "value").read[String](email))
            .orElse Reads.pure("")
```

Using flatMap, we replace the `type` reads by the correct reads on `value` if the `type` reads is a success.

Comment: validEmail will test (__\"value")? Validation will be allways with error, because "user" || "group" are not valid email. I want test (__\"value") is email only if (__\"type") equals "user" || "group". I need `???` as value from (__\"type")

Comment: oh ok sorry I think i see what you mean it's going to be longer :) what should happen to value if the type is something else, just a string ?

Comment: for 'default' type - empty string, for 'domain' type - (__\"value") value. other types restricted by (__\"type") read.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Jean, you are pointing me in the right direction.

`flatMap` and `filter` helps me, and i have

```
case class AclRuleScope(kind: String, value: Option[String])

val aclRuleScopeRead = (
    (__ \ "type").read[String] and
    (__ \ "type").read[String](pattern("^(default|user|group|domain)$".r)).flatMap {
      case t if "user".equals(t) || "group".equals(t) =>
        (__ \ "value").readNullable[String](email)
          .filter(ValidationError(s"error.acl.scope.value omitted for '$t' type"))(_.isDefined)
          .filter(ValidationError(s"error.acl.scope.value not defained for '$t' type"))(_.exists(_.nonEmpty))
      case "domain" =>
        (__ \ "value").readNullable[String]
          .filter(ValidationError("error.acl.scope.value omitted for 'domain' type"))(_.isDefined)
          .filter(ValidationError("error.acl.scope.value not defained for 'domain' type"))(_.exists(_.nonEmpty))
      case "default" =>
        (__ \ "value").readNullable[String]
          .filter(ValidationError("error.acl.scope.value must be omitted for 'default' type"))(_.isEmpty)
    }
)(AclRuleScope.apply _)
```